# Error getting when passing parameter through pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When I'm trying to invoke pig script with property file then I'm getting error:

```
pig -P /mapr/ANALYTICS/apps/PigTest/pig.properties -f pig_if_condition.pig
```

> ```
> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-0.98.4/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
> 15/05/20 15:42:52 ERROR pig.Main: ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Unable to parse properties file
> ```
>
> '/mapr/ANALYTICS/apps/PigTest/pig.properties'
>       15/05/20 15:42:52 WARN pig.Main: There is no log file to write to.
>       15/05/20 15:42:52 ERROR pig.Main: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse properties file
>   '/mapr/ANALYTICS/apps/PigTest/pig.properties'
>               at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:343)
>               at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Pig script is:

```
 test = load '$path' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ip:chararray,country:chararray);
 DUMP test;
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add the contents of the properties file please.

Answer (score 1):

-param (-p) is to specify a single parameter. To specify parameter file we have to use **-param_file** attribute.

**Short Cut Commands :**

1. -m same as -param_file
2. -p same as -param

**Usage :**

```
 pig  -param_file {property_file} -f {pig_file}
```

**example :**

```
 pig  -param_file a.properties -f a.pig
```

**Pig Script : a.pig**

```
A = LOAD '$INPUT' USING  PigStorage(',') AS (country_code:chararray, country_name:chararray);
DUMP A;
```

**Property File : a.properties**

```
INPUT=a.csv
```

**test file : a.csv**

```
IN,India
US,United States
UK,United Kingdom
```

**Output :**

```
 (IN,India)
 (US,United States)
 (UK,United Kingdom)
```