# Passing Parameter in pig

Tags: apache-pig

```
A = load '$path' using PigStorage('$Delimiter') as ($table_schema);
```

I want to pass these parameter in pig command dynamically.

Can any help me in this by showing an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**test.cfg**

```
path=/input/file/path
delimiter=,
table_schema=requiredschema:chararray
```

**N.B.** Valid values to be given for above keys before test run.

**test.pig**

```
A = load '$path' using PigStorage('$delimiter') as ($table_schema);
DUMP A;
```

**Invocation :**

> pig -f test.pig -m test.cfg
>
> -f : To specify pig file name
>   -m : To specify the param file where

**Ref** : [Error getting when passing parameter through pig script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352659/error-getting-when-passing-parameter-through-pig-script/30359884#30359884) for a similar use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response but if test.cfg file has multiple path,delimiter,schema of other table also then how we will specify for a particular table???

Comment: @Sanjeev : you need to have unique keys in the cfg file.